# Bash dialog not reading from print() python

Tags: python, bash, dialog

I want to run `dialog --gauge` from print()

Python file is like this

```
process1
print(30) #updates the gauge percentage to 30
process2
print(60) #updates the gauge percentage to 60
process3
print(100) # completes and exit the gauge
```

```
python run.py | dialog --gauge "Running program" 10 30 0
```

but the gauge is not updating or we can say python prints them at the last in an instant and not like they way they normally prints in terminal

How can I fix that, please tell

Comment: This question is unclear: What is `dialog`? Where is `print`? When is the end?

Answer (score 1):

Not easy to answer if you don't provide the code.

But I am pretty sure you are missing a `flush=True` argument to your print.

```py
import time
for i in range(100):
    print(i, flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```

works fine.

Some explanation about why it is needed: I/O are buffered, for obvious efficiency reason. That goes for print to. So there are different criteria to decide when to effectively do the print, that is when to empty (flush) the buffer and send the chars in it to whatever process is reading (for example, the terminal, in charge of rendering them, for an interactive process; or a process whose standard input is linked to our standard output through a pipe).

- Obviously when output buffer is full. That is the most efficient, buffer size being optimized from different hardware optimums. Unless there are some applicative reasons not to do that
- For interactive process (just python ran in a terminal), whenever a newline is printed. No need to bother the terminal char by char. Things are printed lines by lines. For most "line oriented" programs that is perfectly sufficient (oldie rant: don't forget that "terminals", which we should call "terminal emulators" are just an imitation of physical terminals, which, themselves, where some "paperless printer" replacing former printers. This is really "line oriented". There is a reason why CLI are not called "TCI" for "text command interface". Interaction with shells and terminal are mainly "line oriented").
- But for non interactive process, there is no reason to treat newline differently. What is waiting for our output is neither a printer, nor anything imitating it. It is just another process, reading chars and processing them. There is no reason, a priori, to worry about interactivity.
- Sometimes, tho, you need other rules that those default one. For example, because you are printing lines very slowly, and you want the terminal not to wait a newline before updating it. Or because you are feeding another process through a pipe, quite slowly too, and you don't want that other process to have to wait for your buffer to be full. Or, in your case, because you know that even tho your print are not directly sent to a terminal, but to another process, that is still an interactive application.
- In those cases, you can force the flushing of the buffer after the print, with keyword argument `flush=True`

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I have some process in file, and I want to print those after the each process completes.
Sorry, for incomplete  question, I haved edited it so please tell how to use flush there..

Comment: @decipher That doesn't change my answer. You need those print to flush the buffer (so that they are printed immediatly). So just add the parameter ``flush=True`` to all those ``print``: ``print(30, flush=True)``, ``print(60, flush=True)``, etc.